# Not sure why rpsGame isn't being used? Is my syntax wrong?

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React and was wondering why this return an error

```
import React from 'react';
import rpsGame from './rpsGame'

function App() {
  return (
    <rpsGame />
  )
}

export default App;
```

this return with the error

```
'rpsGame' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars
```

Am I making some sort of syntax error that I'm not seeing?

Comment: try to add rpsGame tag in another tag like dev tag

Comment: Yeah I tried that. Didn't work

Comment: change the name to CamelCase, and make sure that, you export it as a default from rpsGame file itself